# Most recent date for list sorted by values

Tags: python

I have a list that looks roughly like this:

```py
mylist = [[2, 20200101], [2, 20200108], [2, 20200101], [1, 20200110], [1, 20200101]]
```

It is a list of lists, each of which has a value as the first element, and a date as the second. I want to choose the list which first has the highest value (2 in this case) then the most recent date, (20200108 - 8th Jan 2020, in this case)
I know you can pass a lambda function to the built in `max()` function, like below, but I am not sure how to handle choosing the max of first the value, then the date?

```py
max(mylist, key=lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: The default comparison for lists already works the way you want.  Did you try just doing `max(mylist)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default `max` works from the first index to the last in an iterable sorting.

```
mylist = [[2, 20200101], [2, 20200108], [2, 20200101], [1, 20200110], [1, 20200101]]
max(mylist)
```

OR

You can pass two keys!

```
mylist = [[2, 20200101], [2, 20200108], [2, 20200101], [1, 20200110], [1, 20200101]]
max(mylist, key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks, in trying to produce a minimal example, I had actually oversimplified my example. In my actual problem each item is an object with `obj.value` and `obj.date`, so I need to be able to specify the keys like in your second example. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Python, lists compare lexicographically by default. This means that the first element is compared, then the next, and so on, which is exactly what you want. (As a side note, shorter lists will be less than longer lists) So, you can just `max` without a key:

```py
max(mylist)
```